# Edit value in a json from an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I hav an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [fruit] => Banana
    [country] => Canada
)
```

How can I update my json file with a loop with these new datas ?

My json is a file and it looks lile this:

```
{"fruit" : "Cherry", "country" : "Mexico", "weight" : "28"}
```

**Note: I want to update the value fruit and country, not all the json.**

Thanks.

Comment: why not to re-print your json with the updated array?

Comment: @Fabio, it an external on. I've updated the question with the actual structure.

Comment: @fadeys.work because I do not want to loose other value witch are not in my array.

Comment: [`fread()`](http://php.net/fread) + [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode)/[`_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) + [`fwrite()`](http://php.net/fwrite). What is your question?

Comment: You can decode your json as an array, loop throw it and update it while iterating

Comment: could you please explain what is it that your trying to do? I still believe that re-print is the best option. just show us the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said you can decode your json as an associative array (note the use of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.json-decode.php) with second parameter set on `true`), loop throw it and update it while iterating. Finally encode to json again as follow

```
$array = array('fruit' => 'Banana', 'country' => 'Canada');
$json = '{"fruit" : "Cherry", "country" : "Mexico", "weight" : "28"}';
$mjson = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if(isset($mjson[$key])) { 
        $mjson[$key] = $val;
    }
}

$jjson = json_encode($mjson);
print_r($jjson);

//Output: {"fruit":"Banana","country":"Canada","weight":"28"}
```

[**`Live demo`**](http://codepad.org/nBhqRktS)

Comment: my json is an external file. How to edit your second line ? Thanks.

Comment: How do you load that file? You can simply store it in `$json` variable

Comment: Can I make a file_get_contents on it ?

Comment: Yeah just `$json = file_get_contents('address_here');` replace `address_here` with real address and you should be ready to go

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = /** some json string **/
$json = json_decode($input, true); // to assoc array
// update values
$json["fruit"] = "Cherry";
$json["country"] = "Mexico";
$json["weight"] = "28";

$ouput = json_encode($json); // back to json

// save to file etc.
```

Does this help?

Comment: No because I want a loop. I do not want to write all the value each time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly edit the file like it is an object. 
First you need to read the file, than decode json:

e.g:

```
$string='{"name":"John Adams"}';
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
```

Remember if you use second parameter "true" in json_a you will get associative array. Something like this:

```
$json_a=array("name"=>"John Adams");
```

But if you want to have an object don't set second parameter:

```
$string='{"name":"John Adams"}';
$json_o=json_decode($string);
```

Here json_decode($string) returns an object. Now you can do this:

```
echo $json_o->name;
```

When you modify the json object, write it back to the file.